# Use Jenkins build release with Maven release plugin failed on the SSH key credentials

Tags: java, git, jenkins, ssh, maven-release-plugin

Today I had use the Jenkins release plugin with maven build a release but is was failed. Had check the log but the error out seems strange. Also I had build the job with Git and maven, use the SSH safe mode. There were all success before `tag SCM` process, then throws a message `[ERROR] *** Please tell me who you are.` Why?

The environment in my local the more detail see blow:

1. Git `git version 2.6.3.windows.1`
2. Git Repository Server use GitBlit1.6(use SSH safe model)
3. CI Server use the Jenkins ver.1.6.42.3
4. OS use the Windows8.1

The maven project parent module setting `pom.xml` file like blow:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github.elkan1788</groupId>
    <artifactId>release-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>release-parent</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <project.env>develop</project.env>
                <project.version>1.0.3</project.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>stable</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <project.env>stable</project.env>
                <project.version>1.0.2</project.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.10</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.github.elkan1788</groupId>
                <artifactId>release-common</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-source</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadoc</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                        <arguments>-Pstable</arguments>
                        <pushChanges>true</pushChanges>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <scm>
        <url>https://git-scm.com/</url>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://admin@localhost:29418/maven-release-learn.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://admin@localhost:29418/maven-release-learn.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <name>Nexus Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://192.168.10.140/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Nexus Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://192.168.10.140/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

The Jenkins console out message like blow:

```
Started by user Admistrator
Building in workspace D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\jobs\release-develop\workspace
 > D:\DevelopTools\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > D:\DevelopTools\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url ssh://admin@senhuili.sao.so:29418/maven-release-learn.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://admin@senhuili.sao.so:29418/maven-release-learn.git
 > D:\DevelopTools\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials SSH KEY
 > D:\DevelopTools\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://admin@senhuili.sao.so:29418/maven-release-learn.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > D:\DevelopTools\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > D:\DevelopTools\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/develop^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision e11fe83abdb40fa2801f693d8a52023241417fec (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
 > D:\DevelopTools\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > D:\DevelopTools\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f e11fe83abdb40fa2801f693d8a52023241417fec
 > D:\DevelopTools\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list e11fe83abdb40fa2801f693d8a52023241417fec # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 63809
[source] $ D:\DevelopTools\Java\jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -cp D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-agent-1.7.jar;D:\DevelopTools\apache-maven-3.3.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;D:\DevelopTools\apache-maven-3.3.3/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main D:\DevelopTools\apache-maven-3.3.3 D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.53.3.jar D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-interceptor-1.7.jar D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.7.jar 63809
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\jobs\release-develop\workspace\source\pom.xml -s D:\DevelopTools\apache-maven-3.3.3\conf\settings.xml -gs D:\DevelopTools\apache-maven-3.3.3\conf\settings.xml -DdevelopmentVersion=1.0.2-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=1.0.1 -DscmCommentPrefix=[maven-release-plugin] -Dresume=true release:prepare release:perform
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] release-parent
[INFO] release-common
[INFO] release-web
[INFO] maven-release-learn
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building maven-release-learn 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) @ maven-release-learn ---
[INFO] Resuming release from phase 'scm-tag'
[INFO] Tagging release with the label 1.0.1...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git tag -F C:\Windows\TEMP\maven-scm-343084628.commit 1.0.1"
[INFO] Working directory: D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\jobs\release-develop\workspace\source
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] release-parent ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] release-common ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] release-web ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] maven-release-learn ................................ FAILURE [  2.185 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.986 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-05T10:04:54+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/248M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project maven-release-learn: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] *** Please tell me who you are.
[ERROR] 
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\jobs\release-develop\workspace\source\release-web\pom.xml to io.github.elkan1788/release-web/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/release-web-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] Run
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
[ERROR] git config --global user.name "Your Name"
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] to set your account's default identity.
[ERROR] Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] fatal: empty ident name (for <SYSTEM@SenhuiLi.(none)>) not allowed
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :maven-release-learn
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\jobs\release-develop\workspace\source\release-common\pom.xml to io.github.elkan1788/release-common/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/release-common-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\jobs\release-develop\workspace\source\pom.xml to io.github.elkan1788/maven-release-learn/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-release-learn-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\DevelopTools\Jenkins-1.642\jobs\release-develop\workspace\source\release-parent\pom.xml to io.github.elkan1788/release-parent/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/release-parent-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Check the error message found that seems need setting git user.name and user.email. But this things also is well in my local machine, and the maven release:prepare can running in `CMD`. So what's the wrong?

**Supplement**

The Jenkins and Git all run in my local, and the git global setting is Ok, see blow:

```
$ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=D:/DevelopTools/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
merge.tool=kdiff3
diff.guitool=kdiff3
core.editor="D:/DevelopTools/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe" fileeditor
core.autocrlf=True
difftool.kdiff3.path=D:/DevelopTools/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
difftool.kdiff3.cmd="D:/DevelopTools/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
mergetool.kdiff3.path=D:/DevelopTools/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
i18n.filesencoding=utf-8
push.default=current
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url=ssh://admin@local:29418/maven-release-learn.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.develop.remote=origin
branch.develop.merge=refs/heads/develop
user.email=elkan1788@gmail.com
user.name=elkan1788
```

Comment: Is this jenkins build was successful at earlier ? or this setup u trying to execute first time only @elkan

Comment: so is it just that user.name and user.email are not set on your build machine, but are set on your local?

Comment: @VikrantKashyap None, there were not successful since run maven release.

Comment: @eis Sorry, there had not explain the environment, there all thing running in my local machine. And the git commit or push command can be OK in `CMD`.

Comment: I don't really understand, but your problem seems to be that you haven't set user.name and user.email for your jenkins job running the maven release.

Comment: @eis Oh, but I really had complete the git settings. And the Jenkins also use the same git in local machine. Is there can set special setting in Jenkins settings? I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

It's so strange, search the answer on official website [GitPlugin-Gotchas](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Gotchas). There need run `git config user.name "xxx"` under the Jenkins work space just can effective. make this one. Remember it.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in your build log, you just have to set the user.name and user.email information for the user running your Jenkins service (--> Administrator?)

On your Windows machine, open a session with the user running Jenkins and launch the following commands:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks your answer. You suggest I had try the first time. But also I mean the `CMD` use the git command were successful, but Jenkins not. I don't known why?  Also had update the git config list in problem. I think there maybe some config in Jenkins settings but I can't found it.

Comment: OK thanks for the update. Jenkins is running as a service on your machine? If the answer is yes, can you check what is the Windows account used to launch the service? If it's Local System account, can you change it to Administrator and relaunch the service?

Comment: By the default Jenkins running under the Windows Administrator account, this one can be the problem? Also there have new question, the git push run failed. But also it had use SSH key clone project  why can not  same as push command? By the way it can run the git push in Jenkins work space folder.

Comment: Please open a session with the Administrator account and launch the following command: git config -l

Comment: Do you have a value for the user.email and user.name variables?

Comment: Just once again, I had also set the global user.name and user.email in git config. But it strange they can't work with Jenkins. And the Jenkins official said it need add special user.name and email in Jenkins work space folder. Then it will run well.

Comment: On my node, these information are stored at the user level, in the home directory (/home/jenkins/.gitconfig, I'm on Linux). Can you check you have a .gitconfig file in your jenkins user root folder?

Comment: Thanks for attention. This problem were solved. you can check my answer. And also show for you the git global setting can find out in problem description. There just the Jenkins special setting not care the OS environment.